# How do I remove a line from a continuous path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, adobe-fireworks

I'm using Fireworks and I'd like to know how to remove this line that is in red? The result should be just a line in the form of an arch.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  All I had to do was select the path (as shown in my question) and then click "Open/Close Contours" button under the Path window under "Alter Paths:" section.

[image]

This was the result:

[image]